# how to explode all columns of a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have got a DataFrame like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               brand|              diesel|                 e10|                  e5|         houseNumber|                  id|              isOpen|                 lat|                 lng|                name|               place|            postCode|              street|               Datum|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[TOTAL, ARAL, She...|[1.049, 1.029, 1....|[1.249, 1.209, 1....|[1.269, 1.229, 1....|[49, 12-14, ,  , ...|[4409a024-b190-4b...|[true, true, true...|[50.93128, 50.952...|[6.962356, 6.9616...|[TOTAL KOELN, Ara...|[KOELN, Köln, KOE...|[50676, 50668, 50...|[HOLZMARKT, Riehl...|2016-08-01 10:50:...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Basically all columns are arrays. It is based on nested JSON data.
I tried to explode it. But that is only possible with one column in a select statement. Do you know a why how I can unpack all values at once in `pyspark` so that the relations are kept?

Answer (score 0):

May be if you first map everything to one column, then explode, then split.

```
df=sc.parallelize([[[1,2,3,4],[10, 20,30,40]]]).toDF()
F=udf(lambda x,y: [[x[i],y[i]]\
  for i in range(4)],ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))

df.withColumn('merge',F(df._1,df._2))\
  .select(['merge', functions.explode(col('merge'))])
```

First, df outputs

```
+------------+----------------+
|          _1|              _2|
+------------+----------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|[10, 20, 30, 40]|
+------------+----------------+
```

Then the last column is what you need to split :

```
+--------------------+-------+
|               merge|    _c0|
+--------------------+-------+
|[WrappedArray(1, ...|[1, 10]|
|[WrappedArray(1, ...|[2, 20]|
|[WrappedArray(1, ...|[3, 30]|
|[WrappedArray(1, ...|[4, 40]|
+--------------------+-------+
```